# what's difference between cc_library and cc_import

Tags: bazel

what's difference between [cc_library](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library) and [cc_import](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_import) when import prebuild so library.

I noticed that

1. `cc_library` can use multi library but `cc_import` can just use one.
2. `cc_library` can use `strip_include_prefix` but `cc_import` not.

Comment: One of them compiles, the other does not, I believe. Can you link the documentation into your question?

Comment: One Difference is cc_import has and cc_library don't have the "interface_library" attribute. This attribute helps import a DLL (shared library on Windows) and allow other targets to depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `cc_library` and `cc_import` is that the first one is intended to compile a shared library (`.so`/`.dll` files) and make it available as a dependency for other targets, such as executables or tests. It essentially requires you to have your whole library source code and builds from scratch, meanwhile cc_import is used to link prebuild libraries that already exist in your system. This way, you can use external dependencies like Boost or Qt and do not need to do a clean build of those libraries.

Comment: Where do I find more info regarding strip_include_prefix

Is the strip_include_prefix used differently with cc_import and cc_library?

Comment: @varshneydevansh cc_import doesn't have the strip_include_prefix property. If you want to achieve a similar functionality, you would need the libraries to be installed in standard system destinations (such as /lib or /usr/local/lib) and only specify the name of the library in the name attribute, and set system_provided flag to true.